# how do I treat html in a loop when using MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, refactoring

Can someone please show me how to do this basic thing using Zend Framework MVC?

I'm looping over the timestamp data and populating my table that way.  i don't understand how I would pull my presentation HTML from this loop and stick it in the view?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<table>
<?php
  $day = date("j");
  $month = date("m");
  $year = date("Y");        
  $currentTimeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$day"); 
  $numDays = date("t", $currentTimeStamp); 
  $counter = 0; 

            for($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++, $counter++) 
            { 
                $timeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$i"); 
                if($i == 1) 
                { 
                // Workout when the first day of the month is 
                $firstDay = date("w", $timeStamp); 

                for($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++) 
                echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; 
                } 

                if($counter % 7 == 0) {
                  echo "</tr><tr>"; 
                }

                    echo "<td>" .$i . "</td>";

            }
?> 
</table>
```

I'm wanting to turn the above code into functions, but the HTML is throwing me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

******Edited**** (mvc solution added)

Don't clutter your code with unnecessary functions, partials, etc. Why bother with HTML from the start, when you can create your data, *then* transform it into an HTML table? Here's the MVC sample (the following code suppose a one module project called 'default', modify accordingly if the project is module based) :

**[listing 1]** application/controller/IndexController.php

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
   public function indexAction() {
      $this->view->calData = new Default_Model_Calendar('2010-07-17');
   }
}
```

**[listing 2]** application/models/Calendar.php

```
class Default_Model_Calendar {
   /* @var Zend_Date */
   private $_date;
   /* @param Zend_Date|string|int $date */
   public function __construct($date) {
      $this->_date = new Zend_Date($date);
   }
   /* @return Zend_Date */
   public function getTime() {
      return $this->_date;
   }
   public function getData() {
      // normally, fetch data from Db
      // array( day_of_month => event_html, ... )
      return array(
         1 => 'First day of month',
         4 => '<span class="holiday">Independence Day</span>',
         17 => '<img src="path/to/image.png" />'
         //...
      );
   }
}
```

**[lisging 3]** application/view/scripts/index/index.phtml

```
echo $this->calendarTable($this->calData);
```

**[listing 4]** application/view/helpers/CalendarTable.php

```
class Default_View_Helper_CalendarTable extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
   private $_calData;
   public function calendarTable($calData = null) {
      if (null != $calData) {
         $this->_calData = $calData;
      }

      return $this;
   }

   public function toString() {
      $curDate = $this->_calDate->getTime();
      $firstDay = clone $curDate();  // clone a copy to modify it safely
      $firstDay->set(Zend_Date::DAY, 1);

      $firstWeekDay = $firstDay->get(Zend_Date::WEEKDAY);
      $numDays = $curDate->get(Zend_Date::MONTH_DAYS);

      // start with an array of empty items for the first $firstweekDay of the month
      $cal = array_fill(0, $firstweekDay, '&nbsp;');
      // fill the rest of the array with the day number of the month using some data if provided
      $calData = $this->_calData->getData();
      for ($i=1; $i<=$numDays; $i++) {
         $dayHtml = '<span class="day-of-month">' . $i . '</span>';
         if (isset($calData[$i])) {
            $dayHtml .= $calData[$i];
         }
         $cal[] = $dayHtml;
     }

     // pad the array with empty items for the remaining days of the month
     //$cal = array_pad($cal, count($cal) + (count($cal) % 7) - 1, '&nbsp;');
     $cal = array_pad($cal, 42, '&nbsp;');   // OR a calendar has 42 cells in total...

     // split the array in chunks (weeks)
     $calTable = array_chunk($cal, 7);
     // for each chunks, replace them with a string of cells
     foreach ($calTable as & $row) {
        $row = implode('</td><td>', $row);
     }
     // finalize $cal to create actual rows...
     $calTable = implode('</td></tr><tr><td>', $calTable);

     return '<table class="calendar"><tr><td>' . $calTable . '</td></tr></table>';
   }
   public function __toString() {
      return $this->__toString();
   }
}
```

With this code, you can even set exactly what you want within the `$cal` array before calling `array_chunk` on it. For example, `$cal[] = $dayHtml . '<a href="#">more</a>';`

This also follow true MVC as data (in `Default_Model_Calendar`) and view (in `Default_View_Helper_CalendarTable`) are completely separated, giving you the freedom to use any other model with the view helper, or simply not using any view helper with your model!

Comment: Hey thanks.  This is working very well for me.  I just returned $calTable and sent it to the view and it works great!  Thanks again.

Comment: if this code is generated outside a view script, or outside a view helper, then you are breaking the MVC pattern (because you're generating HTML--view--data outside the view fragment of your dispatch request :) ) However, glad it helped!

Comment: I am using Zend Framework, so I want to stick with (and learn) MVC. After the $calTable = implode line above, I returned calTable. I created a new instance of the code as an object from the controller and then displayed it in the view. Sorry if I'm missing correct terminology. Is this the correct way? It is working, but I do want to follow proper MVC. That was the basis for this question-I'm not sure how to handle this situation and keep the HTML only in the view.

Comment: technically, you could create a view helper that would accept an array as parameter, for example $data; that array would be populated with whatever event you need to be displayed in your calendar table. The view helper would then have this code in it, and populate $cal with the data in the given $data array. So, your controller calls a model that returns the $data array and sets it in the view ($this->view->calData = $data;). In your view, echo the view helper's returned value (the given code) with $this->createCalendarTable($this->calData); ...Is this clear?

Comment: I generally understand, but I have never had to do something like determine the split of the table based on the array.  So the above code won't work in a pure MVC fashon is that correct?  Would you be willing to show me how you split that array so the view would know wether it is just feeding to a '<td>' or a new row?  That's what I don't understand.  I figured there must be an easy way to do this with partialLoop, but I'm still a newbie so I don't really understand that well enough to get my code to work with it.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's almost 5am here so I have to rest, but I will look at it in the morning.

Comment: yeah... it's right about that here too.... going to bed now :) Glad I could help!